# How to match email address that with repeat number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How to find email address that below:

- repeat with 1 same number,like 111111@qq.com 222222@qq.com 3333@qq.com
- increment or decrement numbers,like 123456@qq.com 4567890@qq.com
- repeat like 123123@qq.com 12341234@qq.com

because these email is not allowed to register at the mail hosting.

Comment: Why do you think that they're wrong?

Comment: Because these mailboxes are not allowed to register at qq.com @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: That doesn't make the email address "bad", just not valid *for that host*.

Comment: I have no clue what the rules are *for that host*. Have you tried asking them?

Comment: For some discussion of the complexity of email address formats, have a look at: ["Stop Validating Email Addresses With Regex"](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 1):

This re matches the ones you listed:

```
re.match("^[0-9]+@qq\.com$", "1111@qqs.com")
```